# Use common table expression query

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, common-table-expression

I have a common table expression which works fine on the mssql editor. However, when I use the same populating a string variable in PHP and using `odbc_exec($dbhandle,$query )` it returns no rows. No error is thrown. Is this a limitation on PHP? Other select queries on various other tables run fine. Issue is only with the CTE statement.

Comment: Can you show the statement that is causing the problem?

Comment: Run the SQL Profiler tool from SSMS  to intercept SQL queries that are coming to the server. Then trigger a request from your PHP client that should send the query containing CTE. Make this check to be sure that the query containing the CTE is coming to the server (and not getting filtered out by `odbc_exec`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but it wasn't answered and it's a high ranking Google result so I thought I'd chip in.

None of the native PHP methods of querying an MS SQL server can support Common Table Expressions ('WITH' clauses). These include the mssql_* libraries AND the odbc_* libraries.

This is due to the way MS SQL handles it's CTE's (by creating macros for execution). The good news is that Microsoft's libraries (sqlsrv_*) DO support CTE's natively.

The sqlsrv_* libraries operate identically to mssql_* in terms of creating and consuming connections, simple queries, prepared statements etc. They are almost a 'drop-in' replacement for using mssql_* or odbc_* with MS SQL servers, and are significantly faster to boot.

You can obtain the sqlsrv libraries from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=20098). As of this writing, 2.x is fine for SQL 2008, but 3.x is needed for SQL 2012.